# FormData и XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, xhr

Проблема заключается в том что, не получается отправить File, через FormData.

Имеется inptut

```
<input id="Music" type="file">
```

Добавил Слушителя

```
    Music.addEventListener("change", LoadMusic);
```

В LoadMusic просто  даю src и MusicFile даю File

```
function LoadMusic(e) {
    var Files = e.target.files;
    var FileName = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    if (Files.length != 1) {
        alert("Файл должен быть 1");
    } else if (Files[0].name.substr(Files[0].name.length - 4) != ".mp3")//Add check Case 
      {
        alert("Поддерживается только mp3");
    } else {
//Player this document.getElementByID("Music")
        Player.src = FileName;
        Player.load();
        MusicFile = e.target.files[0];
    }
}
```

А после определенных манипуляций, вызываю функцию SendResult

```
function SendResult() {
var Data = new FormData();
var TestArray = ArrayNodes;
for (var i = 0; i < NumElem; i++) {
    delete TestArray[i]._Node;
    delete TestArray[i]._Pick;
}
var js = (JSON.stringify(TestArray));
Data.append("LevelJSON",js);
Data.append("fil",MusicFile);
Data.append("UserName",ClientName);
var NameLevel = document.getElementById("NameLevel");
Data.append("LevelName",NameLevel.value);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', 'Utilis/SendMap.php',true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState != 4) return;
        console.log(this.responseText);
}
xhr.send(Data);
xhr = null;
```

}

PHP - файлик содержит

```
if (isset($_POST['LevelJSON'])){
    $Path=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ."/Maps/".$_POST['UserName']."/".$_POST['LevelName']."/";
    echo($_POST['LevelJSON']);
    mkdir($Path,0777,true);
    $File = fopen($Path.$_POST['LevelName'].".json", "w");
    fwrite($File, "var Data = '".$_POST['LevelJSON']."';"); 
    fclose($File);
}else{
echo($_FILES['fil']['tmp_name']);
}
```

Вывод Response....

```
<br />
```

**Notice**:  Undefined index: fil in **/var/www/html/Utilis/SendMap.php** on line **16**
(То есть в POST запросе нету LevelJSON)
Где допущена Ошибка?
*Возможно ошибка в xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");*

Comment: где здесь `SendMap` у которого должно быть как минимум 16 строк?

Comment: "PHP - файлик содержит"

Comment: `Где допущена Ошибка?` - что вы хотите в результате? чтоб у вас не было `Undefined index: fil in /var/www/html/Utilis/SendMap.php`  или чтоб  входил в условие `if (isset($_POST['LevelJSON']))` ? ))

Comment: У меня при вставке файла (В input) Параметры POST запроса не отправляются. (То есть 
$_POST['LevelJSON'] - undefined
$_POST['UserName'] - undefined
$_FILES['fil']['tmp_name'] - undefined
и так далее...
НО.... Без вставки файла, все выше перечисленные параметры (Вроде кроме $_FILES) отправляются без проблем.

Comment: Думаю что проблема в xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в MAX_UPLOAD (php.ini)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, проблема в этом:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
```